Dual datepicker jQuery selection
I am building a date picker from scratch as a learning exercise. My date picker has two months side by side, and my question is, what does the jQuery look like for picking a start date and end date, allowing for the user to change their mind and have both dates on the same month, or on opposite months?
My HTML
<div class="calendar left">
    <div class="calendar-days">
        <div class="calendar-day" day="1">1</div>
        <div class="calendar-day" day="2">2</div>   
        <div class="calendar-day" day="3">3</div>
        <div class="calendar-day" day="4">4</div>
        <div class="calendar-day" day="5">5</div>
        ...
        ...
    </div>
</div>
<div class="calendar right">
    <div class="calendar-days">
        <div class="calendar-day" day="1">1</div>
        <div class="calendar-day" day="2">2</div>   
        <div class="calendar-day" day="3">3</div>
        <div class="calendar-day" day="4">4</div>
        <div class="calendar-day" day="5">5</div>
        ...
        ...
    </div>
</div>

Say the left month is August and the right month is September... they can choose start date August 5th and end date August 17th, or start date August 5th and end date September 22nd, or start date September 8th and end date September 12th, etc... there's three scenarios.
Selecting the start date is obvious with a click event, and adding a selected class to that day. But how do I only allow two days to be selected at any given time across both calendars?

If I understand correctly, you want to limit date selection to two.
You can do so by verifying a condition inside your event handler :
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".calendar-day").on("click", function(){
    //To remove a selection if it is clicked once more
    if($(this).hasClass("selected"){
        $(this).removeClass("selected")
    }
    //To select a date and limit the number of selections
    else if($(".selected").length<2){
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    }
  })
})

Note that I used you idea of adding a selected class to the date.
This code does not really do any verification on whether start date is inferior to the end one, but instead lets the user select an end date first and a start date then, or the opposite
Hope this helped !

This helps for one choice, but what if they choose a start date and end date, but then want to click a third day to change their mind? This would return false.

Thing is, we don't know whether the user wants the new date should be attributed to the start or the end date... Unless you chose it and force an odd-numbered choice to stand for start date, and an even-numbered choice to stand for the end date.
Another solution would be the one I edited in the solution above, but the odd/even-numbered-choice one looks the best one to me...

Yeah, I was thinking the first date you choose is start, second is end, and third, if it is after start, becomes new end date, otherwise clears the calendars and selects the last clicked date as start?

The HTML in the question has two datepickers, one for start and the other for end, not one datepicker to select a range.

Actually, I may be misunderstanding it. I guess it's just a single datepicker that shows two months at a time (this is a common style in airline and hotel reservation sites).

@barmar correct... that's what makes it confusing.

@Ping let's imagine we use your idea :
Let's say August 15 is start date and August 30 is end date.
If the user then wants start date to be August 16... He can not do it : whenever he clicks on August 16, it will act as end date...
Although you are an a good lead : keeping an eye on wheter the user's current date picking is te first, second, third, etc...
A button to clear and reset the date picking is also an option.
Just as Barmar mentionned, if you want an idea, you can for exemple take a look at airbnb date picker (for when doing a reservation)

$(".selected").length could be a point of issue. Avoid bug prone code.
